# Hibernate, MySQL. Composite PK and Custom Identity Generator

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, generator, composite-primary-key

For simplicity, I'll write the next example that shows my problem. We have 3 entities: division, rank and employee. Basically, every division has its own list of ranks, with different pay grades, so I want my ID for rank to be based upon division and pay grade, so the rank of employees will change based upon their pay grade and the division they are currently working in.

Example: we have 2 divisions, researching and engineering, each division has its own rank list (for simplicity we'll only add one to each, chief engineer and chief researcher respectively). When I reassign my chief engineer from engineering division to researching, he will become a chief researcher.

So the question is, how should I change my entities bellow, to achieve this? Also, how to make a custom generator for my pay grade field inside of Rank entity, so it will automatically increment its value for every unique division?

**Division.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "division")
public class Division {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column
private String name;

@OneToMany
private List<Rank> rankList;

}
```

**Rank.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "rank")
public class Rank {

@ManyToOne
private Division division;

@Column
private Long grade;

@Column
private String name;

}
```

**Employee.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@ManyToOne
private Division division;

@ManyToOne
private Rank rank;

}
```